# how to create image slides builder in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

For example ,refer image below left column show user input, right column shows first slide preview , once you click add new , current preview slide should save state in array increment id, and add more slides. Use select option to switch each slide state preview and update .finaly if you click save All button it should return as object for all slides.

```
images:[
 slide1:{
  id: 1,
  image_url:'www.example.com'
 },
 slide2:{
  id: 2,
  image_url:'www.example.com'
 }
]
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I tired this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905988/react-js-how-to-append-a-component-on-click , but i dont know how to save old state objects and to create form for new image slide